# Static variable in Application class returns null when accessing it

Tags: android, process, intentservice

I am defining a variable in application class like this

```
public static ResultReceiver myResultReceiver = null;
```

In some activities I am extending ResultReceiver and assigning to myResultReceiver, in stop() of activities I am making it null.
Though myResultReceiver is not null yet when I access it from an intentservice it is null. The code was working fine till today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, just may be you have the service on another process using the **[android:process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html)** or **[android:isolatedProcess](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html)** attribute. If so, that makes a separate isolated new process which the Service runs in and it's impossible to read any data from another process even static variables except using **IPC** or **SharedPreferences**.

If you don't need the attribute then remove it and save yourself from the hassle.

Comment: Yes you are write I was using  android:process to kill the service. Then how to kill the intentservice?

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmed Hegazy is correct. Problem was I have added **android:process** in manifest to kill **intent service** because of that I am not able to access.