# I can not get any value from any class to IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

I am trying to pass the value to IntentService Class. But I can not get the value from any class.

I am following like this:

```
    public class ModelClass {

    private static ModelClass mInstance = null;
    Activity mActivity;
    String mString;

    public static ModelClass getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new ModelClass();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public String getmString() {
        return mString;
    }

    public void setmString(String mString) {
        this.mString = mString;
    }



    public void setmActivity(Activity activity){
        mActivity=activity;
    }

    public Activity getmActivity(){
        return mActivity;
    }
}
```

I am setting the value form HomePage like this.

```
public class Home extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ModelClass.getInstance().setmActivity(this);
    ModelClass.getInstance().setmString("Testing String");
  }
}
```

I am receiving the value like this:-

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("On Create==> ");       
        System.out.println("getmString() ==> "+ModelClass.getInstance().getmString());
        System.out.println("getmActivity() ==> "+ModelClass.getInstance().getmActivity());

    }

}
```

But I am here getting null values. If i try to get the value in home page mean I can view the values. Please let me know why I can not get the value in IntentService?

Comment: Can u just try this: Add private ModelClass(){ } in that class. I'm not saying its exact soln. But try it

Comment: @Raghavendra.. No luck..

Comment: Check the Ahmed Hegazy's answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519217/static-variable-in-application-class-returns-null-when-accessing-it